# File Descriptors to asyncio transport/protocol

Tags: python, python-asyncio

Ok, so, I have a Base Protocol and specializations for Streams and Subprocess. I am also trying to rig it up for inherited file descriptors (namely, stdio). This is useful for proxying over ssh, systemd socket activation, etc.

To be clear, I need to get asyncio to wire up a reader file descriptor and writer file descriptor to a Transport and construct a Protocol from it.

Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be anything for that? I can ask it to watch descriptors or get stream objects for them, but I can't seem to wire them up to a transport/protocol pair.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up writing a proxy transport/protocol object: It can act as the protocol for the reader/writer transports, and act as a transport for the actual protocol, shuffling data  between all three.

https://github.com/minecraft-podman/urp/blob/8ed78d12c8abfa7ef067892dda25149d023b03fc/urp/common.py#L286-L364